# Adding a callback to a blazor hybrid in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, blazor, blazor-hybrid

I´m testing some functionality for seeing the possibilities of Blazor hosted inside a Windows Form application. The solution is the one in the documentation, the classic counter.
Now i´m trying to exchange data between the windows and the blazor app, and it works based on this article: [How to interact BlazorWebView and Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494434/how-to-interact-blazorwebview-and-windows-forms/72780073#72780073)

Specifically  if i call this:

`blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "dummy", "222" } });`

I can see the parameter inside the component and use its value.

But i have not been able to use a callback fired inside the component and intercepted in the main form.

This is the callback declaration

```
 [Parameter]

    public EventCallback Callback { get; set; }
```

And in the Windows Form

```
 public async Task DoSomething()
        {
            //anything here
        }
```

And the passing of the method to the component

```
blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Callback",()=> DoSomething() } });
```

I have used several variations of the same thing but always get an error. In this case

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EventCallback

If you defined the parameter of type [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
private async void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    await Callback.InvokeAsync();
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback Callback { get; set; }
```

Then you can pass it like this:

```
blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app",
    new Dictionary<string, object?>
    {
        {"Callback", new EventCallback(null, ()=>{ MessageBox.Show("Hi"); }) }
    });
```

#### Action

If you defined a parameter of type of [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
private void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    Callback?.Invoke();
}

[Parameter]
public Action Callback { get; set; }
```

Then you can pass it like this:

```
blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app",
    new Dictionary<string, object?>
    {
        {"Callback", ()=>{ MessageBox.Show("Hi"); } }
    });
```